# How do I get value of an ArrayList<HashMap> as a String?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I'm using Picasso to get images from a website. (TheMovieDB)

```
System.out.println("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + 
        String.valueOf(posters.get(position).values())
```

I'm just using the code above to test a listView.setOnItemClickListener

Posters:

```
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> posters;
```

The problem is when i click an item in the listview (all the items have the same link for now) it returns this:

```
I/System.out: http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185[/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg]
```

How do i get it to return the posters.get(position).values() as a string? So that it can properly concatenate the String.

I am doing that to get the movie poster links from the API and display in the listview.

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" +
                        String.valueOf(posters.get(position).values()));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: post your listView.setOnItemClickListener code

Comment: can you please post the code of posters arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
System.out.println("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + 
    String.valueOf(posters.get(position).get("yourKey"))
```

Comment: my key is generated by an array, i take a list of ids from the api, put the id as first string and img url as second img

Comment: then pass id in place of yourKey

Comment: I'll try that as soon as i get to my laptop. Thank you for the help. I've looked for so long at the code that i didn't even realise that

Comment: Somewhat. I used .replace() to get rid of the [ ]